# Add custom template 'sub-page' to Custom Post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, pages, templates

I have a custom post type called 'Inspections'

Doing this, you can access an inspection record by going to `example.com/inspections/inspection-slug-here`

However, I want to add some 'sub-pages' if you will:

```
/inspections/<inspection-slug-here>/sub-page1
/inspections/<inspection-slug-here>/sub-page2
```

In this case, I would really like `sub-page1` and `sub-page2` to be templates that I can author in elementor, or something similar.

In a perfect scenario, I would like to  pass the details of the parent (inspection-slug-here) to be loaded in this sub section so I can use custom fields or something of the likes.

Is there anything out there that does this? I am using elementor and an elementor templates tool, but cannot find any ways to do what i want.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in using Plugin, and to add PHP code directly into your Elementor, try the following plugin which will enable to add PHP code directly into your Elementor pages.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/php-everywhere/

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom *Single* template and when saving it, set the display conditions to the posts you want.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This does not answer the question at all unfortunately. The question is how can I map a static page to all pages of a CPT. Creating all these manually would be quite tiresome.

Comment: You'd just select 'All' in that case.